# GCP BigQuery Cost Dashboard doesent match with BigQuery Metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to export the BigQuery metadata to analyse the processed bytes of a query for a given period of time. To do this I create a GCP-Log-Router with the following filter condition:

```
"protoPayload.metadata."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata"
```

I am trying to extract the total billed bytes between **2023-03-01** and **2023-03-16** using the following query:

```sql
#standardSQL
with base AS (
        SELECT
        resource.labels.location,
        protopayload_auditlog.resourceName,
        resource.type,
        protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail ,
        CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson, "$.jobChange.job.jobStats.queryStats.cacheHit") AS BOOL) AS cacheHit,
        CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson, "$.jobChange.job.jobStats.queryStats.totalBilledBytes") as INT64) AS totalBilledBytes,
        CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(protopayload_auditlog.metadataJson, "$.jobChange.job.jobStats.queryStats.totalProcessedBytes") as INT64) AS totalProcessedBytes,
        DATETIME(timestamp, "PST8PDT") as timestamp,
        FROM cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access
      )
      SELECT
        ROUND(sum(totalbilledbytes)/POW(2,40),3) as totalbilledbytes,
      FROM
        base
      WHERE
        timestamp >=  DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2023-03-01 00:00:00','UTC'), "PST8PDT")
      AND
        timestamp <= DATETIME(TIMESTAMP('2023-03-16 23:59:59','UTC'), "PST8PDT")
      AND
        cacheHit is NULL
      AND  
        type = 'bigquery_project'
      AND 
        location = "EU"
```

The query shows that I have consumed approximately **2.061** Tebibytes in the given period. Unfortunately, the GCP Cost Dashboard shows a different billed bytes value (**1.99** Tebibytes):

[GCP Cost Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgJWc.png)

Do you have any idea where this discrepancy comes from?

- Remove duplicates in the original dataset
- Tryout different timeframes
- Tryout different filter conditions

Comment: Time zone? Try the same query in the PST time zone

Comment: I have adjusted the query accordingly. Unfortunately the result (2.06 Tebibytes) still differs significantly from the expected result from the GCP Cost Dashboard (1.99 Tebibytes).